# Workfolw Foundation restart/resume the workflow from the activity that failed

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have a workflow with a number of compensatable activities. If one of these activities cancels I would like to restart/resume the workflow from the activity that failed.

I am thinking of bookmarking and persisting in the cancellation handlers

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb I always persist just before state changing activities so the option to redo is always available.